# How Can I Change the Rename my Project File and Class files in a smooth way with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, resharper, rename

I am finally done with my ASP.NET Webapplicaton and my solution contains three projects: the webapplication itself, WCF and Classlibrary. But I would like to refactor it to change class names, project names, etc. How can I do this in a smooth way so everything doesn't get messed up, like namespaces etc. I also have Resharper but I'm new to that.

When I renamed my Project file and .csproj etc I still have problems with namespaces the new namespace is not working it asks for the old one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've had success using a find/replace on ALL files in the solution (outside of VS).

Comment: You might want to take a look at the *Adjust Namespaces* functionality: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no streamlined way to do everything you're asking. As jbkkd mentioned, it's easy to rename classes, but you'll have challenges with the following:

- Class file names - renaming a class from the source file will not rename the *.cs filename to match (if the file is open for editing and you rename from the Solution Explorer, it should ask you to rename the class)
- You can rename a project name from the Solution Explorer, but this will not automatically rename the namespaces in your code or the physical folder names in your solution (where your project files are contained)
- Depending on the type of ASP.NET application, there could be auto-generated files and/or code-behind files that may not have their class and/or namespace name changed; for example, if you change the class name or namespace in a Global.asax.cs file, you have to also make the changes in the Global.asax file too as it will not be done automatically

ReSharper will help with renaming classes and namespaces, etc., but you'll still have to manually clean things up and depending on how big your solution is, it could be a project in and of itself.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the Class/Object Name(inside the file) > Refactor > Rename.

It'll ask you if you want to preview as well so you know what gets changed and what not.

Comment: I dont see the option Rename when I click on the class/Object name and then click refactor. I only see this following options: Adjust namespaces, move, safe delete and move types into matching files

Comment: No,
Once you open the file - right click on the Class name in the code line, where it says:
`public class THECLASS`

Comment: If I want to rename the project file name how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure about resharper, but without it you'll have to manually change the references to the project manually.